# How does printf with multiple arguments separated by space work

Tags: shell, printf

I have the following `printf` function:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\t%s\n' 100644 blob 8e1e f1.txt 100644 blob 9de7 f2.txt | git mktree
```

Can anyone please explain what it produces and why? I expected to have equal number of formatting options `%s` for each argument string but I have a lot more arguments strings here.

Comment: Run `help printf` to see the shell's built-in documentation for its `printf` builtin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does printf print more arguments than expected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211060/why-does-printf-print-more-arguments-than-expected)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The format is reused as many times as needed to display all arguments.  If there are too few arguments, the missing arguments are treated as empty strings.

#### Examples

Here is an example of a format that specifies two arguments but only one is provided:

```
$ printf '%s ; %s ;\n' a
a ;  ;
```

Here is the same format, this time provided with one too many arguments:

```
$ printf '%s ; %s ;\n' a b c
a ; b ;
c ;  ;
```

Here is the example from the question in which the format expects four arguments.  Since eight arguments are provided the entire format is used twice:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\t%s\n' 100644 blob 8e1e f1.txt 100644 blob 9de7 f2.txt
100644 blob 8e1e        f1.txt
100644 blob 9de7        f2.txt
```

#### Documentation

From man bash:

> The  format  is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments.  If the format requires more arguments than are supplied, the extra format specifications
>                 behave as if a zero value or null string, as appropriate, had been supplied.  The return value is zero on success, non-zero on failure.

Comment: thanks, can you please show how this `reuse` works in my particular case?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, sure, I just added that example to the answer.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot for you elaborate answer! good luck

Comment: And the format is used at least once even if there's no argument, which is annoying in cases like `printf '* %s\n' "$@"` which you have to work around with `[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '* %s\n' "$@"`.

Comment: The zero argument case is a bit of a pain.  but another way is to always have at leas tone argument.  For example a solution to the last comment...   `printf "'%s' " "$0" "$@"`

Comment: `man bash` is different from implementation to implementation. people looking for a static source can figure it out from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html#printf-invocation), the first and second items in the hyphen list